# Visual Studio 2013 - JS debugger triggered from a different app

Tags: javascript, debugging, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013

I have been writing JavaScript inside this windows application called Magaya Explorer. I write 'debugger;' in the code. However, when I run the code it does not trigger Visual Studio 2013 debugger. Prior to this, I had windows 7 with VS2012. I have updated to windows 8 with VS2013 (not sure if made a difference) but now the debugger no longer is triggered in the code.

I tried the following below, but did not work:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z959x58c.aspx

I also tried this one below, but I don't know which file is the debugger.

http://www.thewindowsclub.com/set-default-script-debugger-windows

None have worked so far... any feedback would be of great assistance.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update the JustInTime Debugger in registry.